# How can I add a custom primitive object

Tags: modeling

In lightwave they have a capsule primitive object which I'm finding to use it more often than I thought.

I could export an .obj file or extrude half of a sphere then mirror it, but I thought it would be better to have it on your Shift+A shortcut with the rings and segments choices. 
anyways, I thing it's going to need some scripting knowledge to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to **File** > **User Preferences** > **Add-ons** and search for **Add Mesh: Extra Objects** and enable it.

   Make sure to **Save User Settings** to keep it that way.

[image: 1]

2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > **Mesh** > **Round Cube** to add this object from the add-on.

[image: 2]

3. In the T**ool Shelf** or after pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> select **Operator Presets** and choose **Capsule**.
4. Switch **Type** to **Edges** - this will allow to control horizontal edge loops.

[image: 3]

Now you can control capsule **Radius**, **Length** (by changing Z value), subdivision (**Arc** and **Linear**).